# regular expression match and replace multiple strings

Tags: php, regex

I have this:

```
$only_left_pattern = '/[^-{]\bleft\b/';
$subject = 'body {left: 24px;}\n p {right:30px;}';
$subject = preg_replace($only_left_pattern, 'right', $subject);
echo $subject;
```

I need to declare a pattern for each string I want to match.
If there way I can match right or left and replace according to that?
Example (syntax from my head):

```
$right_left_pattern = '/[^-{](\bleft\b|\bright\b/)';

// if you found left replace with right, if you found right replace with left
// acrording to the order in the pattern
$subject = preg_replace($only_left_pattern, right|left, $subject);
```

What I'm asking if I can do something like my example with PHP or just with regular expression.

I tried Dave's solution

```
$pattern = array('/[^-{]\bleft\b/','/[^-{]\bright\b/');
$replace = array('right','left');
$subject = 'body {left: 24px;} p {right: 24px;}';
$subject = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $subject);
echo $subject;
```

but it doesn't work, I tested the `regex` not as array and it's working.

Comment: [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback), although you can also pass arrays to the first and second arguments of `preg_replace()` - but I suspect a callback is what you want.

Comment: You are asking what now?

Comment: thanks DaveRandom,
tryed this didn't work:
$pattern = array('/[^-{]\bleft\b/','/[^-{]\bright\b/');
$replace = array('right','left');
$subject = 'body {left: 24px;} p {right: 24px;}';
$subject = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $subject);

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is your regular expression.  You have `[^-{]` that means that you are checking for a string that DOES NOT start with a `-` or a `{` but since `{left:` starts with a `{` the match is ignoring it.  I imagine what you're trying to say is only replace the word `left`.  To replace only part of a string you need to use back references like this:

```
$pattern = '/([-{]\b)(left)(\b)/';
$replace = '$1right$3';
$subject = 'body {left: 24px;} p {right: 24px;}';
$subject = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $subject);

// result: body {right: 24px;} p {right: 24px;}
echo $subject;
```

Notice the parentheses in the `$pattern`.  That is grouping those parts together. Also notice the `$n` in the `$replace`. The first parenthesis group `([-{]\b)` is `$1`, the second `(left)` is `$2`, and the third `(\b)` is `$3`.

Now that solves replacing the left -> right but you can't do the array as suggested because this will happen:

```
body {left: 24px;} p {right: 24px;}

Step 1: replace left pattern
body {right: 24px;} p {right: 24px;}

Step 2: replace right pattern
body {left: 24px;} p {left: 24px;}
```

Oops! now you have all left's.  That's not very helpful. What you really want is `preg_replace_callback`. `preg_replace_callback` will run a user defined function for each match.  So what we do is we find all the lefts and rights in one go and then in our function we swap the left/right and return it plus the original string like so:

```
function replaceLeftRight($matches) {
    // get the opposite left/right
    $leftRight = ($matches[2] == 'left') ? 'right' : 'left';
    return $matches[1] . $leftRight . $matches[3];
}   

$pattern = '/([-{]\b)(left|right)(\b)/';
$subject = 'body {left: 24px;} p {right: 24px;}';    
$subject = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'replaceLeftRight', $subject);

// result: body {right: 24px;} p {left: 24px;}
echo $subject;
```